# Como leer correos mediante SMTP desde C#?

Tags: c#, smtp, microsoft-office, outlook, exchangewebservices

Tengo que leer una bandeja de entrada (Inbox Outlook Microsoft Exchange) de un correo electrónico, tengo la cuenta del correo, la contraseña y por parte del servidor de correo tengo el host (el correo esta configurado como SMTP NO POP3 ni IMAP) y el puerto.

Este es mi código

```
private void connection()
    {   
        try
        {

            using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("smtp.miempresa.com", 25, "correoaleer@otracosa.com", "mipasswaor", AuthMethod.Login, false))
            {

                if (client.Supports("IDLE") == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El servidor no soporta IMAP IDLE");
                }
                client.NewMessage += new EventHandler<IdleMessageEventArgs>(OnNewMessage);


            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error no controlado:\n"+ex.Message,"Error");
        }

    }
    static void OnNewMessage(object sender, IdleMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Mensaje nuevo recibido");
        MailMessage m = e.Client.GetMessage(e.MessageUID, FetchOptions.Normal);
        f.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            f.richTextBox1.AppendText("From: " +m.From + "\n"+
                                        "Subject: " +m.Subject+"\n"+
                                         "Body: "+ m.Body+"\n"+
                                         "Attach: "+m.Attachments+"\n");
        });
    }
```

Con este código, lo que quiero, es mostrar en un `RichTextBox` los correos de la bandeja, pero cuando intento conectarme produce el siguiente error:

> 220 SMT-KMCI2004.miempresa.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at
>   Wed, 5 Sep 2018 14:40:40 -0400

Alguna idea del error, u otra forma de leer los correos de Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que los datos son correctos? SMTP generalmente es asociado sólo al envío no a la lectura

Comment: La informacion me la pasa el administrador del servidor de correo, yo solo hago mi requerimiento de la cuenta y me envian la informacion de la cuenta y del server, pero se pudo equivocar, asumiendo que eso paso entonces como lo haria si es POP3?

Comment: ¿Has intentado conectarte a esa cuenta con algún programa de correo como Outlook por ejemplo? para corroborar que tengas acceso a la cuenta.

Comment: Es correcto amigo, si puedo entrar y ver la bandeja con las mismas credenciales que tengo desde outlook.

Comment: Leer correos es más complejo que enviarlos. Como han comentado SMTP es un protocolo de envío. Deberías usar una librería porque a lo más que llegan las librerías oficiales de .NET es a establecer una conexión y que tú implementes el intercambio de mensajes, lo cual es una locura. Te recomiendo Mailkit (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). Es importante conocer lo siguiente. ¿Qué tipos de correo deseas leer? No es lo mismo un correo con texto plano que uno con HTML y adjuntos. Se usan varios tipos MIME y se estructuran de forma un poco distinta. Todo ello influye en la implementación.

Comment: todos los correos son texto plano, y lo unico que quiero leer es el subject(para la actividad que quiero), leer el cuerpo del texto quizas sea opcional, los adjuntos no los quiero leer. Algun link u pagina donde pueda guiarme para continuar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de tanto buscar por SMTP no logre hacer la conexion como yo esperaba, sin embargo encontre otra manera de leer los correos que llegan, obtengo el Subject y el body del correo mediante Outlook.MailItem y de alguna manera puedo continaur con mi proyecto.

Este es el codigo en VB.NET para leer los correos.

```
Import Microsoft.Office.Interop
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Application_Startup()

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
    '**********
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
    '***********
    olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Items

    objNS = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd1(ByVal Item As Object) Handles olInboxItems.ItemAdd

    Dim correo As Outlook.MailItem = Item


    If correo.Subject.Contains("Apruebo") Then
        If correo.SenderEmailType.Contains("EX") Then
            Dim mailfrom As Outlook.AddressEntry = correo.Sender
            Dim senderemail As String = ""

            If mailfrom.AddressEntryUserType = Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry OrElse mailfrom.AddressEntryUserType = Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry Then
                Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = mailfrom.GetExchangeUser()
                If exchUser IsNot Nothing Then
                    senderemail = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
            Else
                senderemail = (CType(correo.Item, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)).SenderEmailAddress
            End If
            MsgBox("El folio fue aprobado por " & senderemail)
        End If


    ElseIf correo.Subject.Contains("No Aprobado") Then
        MsgBox("El Folio no fue aprobado")
    Else

    End If


End Sub
```

El problema es que tengo que tener el correo que deseo leer abierto todo el tiempo y una computadora que este dedicada a este correo, como dije no es lo que yo buscaba pero asi me funciona por el momento.
Espero que a alguien mas le sirva esta respuesta.
*Si alguien tiene una mejor opcion o mejora este codigo espero que lo compartan aqui.
Saludos y gracias.